# Using gregexpr to get position in a string

Tags: regex, r

What I want to do is to extract the position of a certain expression in a character string (length is 22588). I tried it in the following way:

This is the pattern I'm looking for:

```
\n,null,[null,null,12.27,800.54]\n,
\n,null,[null,null,12.58,670.84]\n,
\n,null,[null,null,13.45,750.25]\n,
```

And so on.

I try to give an example:

```
test = "some other stuff \n,null,[null,null,12.27,800.54]\n, other stuff a lot of characters \n,null,[null,null,12.58,670.84]\n, and again  \n,null,[null,null,13.45,750.25]\n,"
```

Now I want to get the positions of the expressions. which have this pattern:

```
\n,null,[null,null,"decimal numbers""comma between decimal numbers""decimal numbers"]\n,
```

This is what I tried:

```
mypattern = "\\\\n,null,\\[\null,null,[:alnum:]\\]\\\\\n,"

gg = gregexpr(mypattern,datalines)
```

Unfortunately this does not work. In the middle I always have these coordinates. So I need a wildcard for them and I also gues R has a problem to read the metacharacter.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: But what if I want to use it with all possible numbers?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by getting the position in a string? It looks like you have a *vector of strings* - do you mean you want the position of elements in the vector that match your regex?

Comment: your pattern cannot work because "." and "," are not "alnum". you can try this pattern: `"\\\n,null,\\[null,null,\\d+\\.\\d+\\,\\d+\\.\\d+\\]\\\n"` or even `"\\\n,null,\\[null,null,\\d{2}\\.\\d{2}\\,\\d{3}\\.\\d{2}\\]\\\n"` if the numbers of digits stay the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with this pattern:

```
"\\\n,null,\\[null,null,\\d+\\.\\d+\\,\\d+\\.\\d+\\]\\\n"
```

or this pattern if the numbers of digits before and after each "." stay the same:

```
"\\\n,null,\\[null,null,\\d{2}\\.\\d{2}\\,\\d{3}\\.\\d{2}\\]\\\n"
```

*With your example:*

```
gregexpr("\\\n,null,\\[null,null,\\d+\\.\\d+\\,\\d+\\.\\d+\\]\\\n",test)
gregexpr("\\\n,null,\\[null,null,\\d{2}\\.\\d{2}\\,\\d{3}\\.\\d{2}\\]\\\n",test)
#[[1]]
#[1]  18  84 129
#attr(,"match.length")
#[1] 32 32 32
#attr(,"useBytes")
#[1] TRUE
```